# Android Gridview in Arabic format

Tags: android, gridview, arabic

I want to display the gridview images in an Arabic format.

Currently I am using `android:rotationX="180"` in my xml and it is working as expected.

But now the problem is if I add any image to the gridview, it is adding in the following way

![currently adding like this]

[image]

but I want to add image for the gridview as fallows:

![Need to added here] 
[image]